# VueJS/Pinia - Computed is still dirty after getter evaluation, likely because a computed is mutating its own dependency in its getter

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I am using Vue 3.4.19 along with Pinia.
A warning shows up in the console and I have narrowed it down to a few reasons.
I would like to eliminate this warning in order to ensure that I follow best practices so this doesn't develop into more serious errors.

**Here is the warning I am getting: **
[Vue warn] Computed is still dirty after getter evaluation, likely because a computed is mutating its own dependency in its getter. State mutations in computed getters should be avoided.

**Here are the pieces of code that I suspect are the culprits:**

```
<template>
  <div class="snackbar">{{ msg.snackBar }}</div>
  <input v-model="textInput" type="text" placeholder="Snackbar text" />
  <button @click="clickButton">Show snackbar</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Snackbar',

  computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useSiteStore, ['msg']),
  },

  data() {
    return {
      textInput: '',
    };
  },

  methods: {
    clickButton() {
      if (this.textInput != '') {
        this.msg.snackBar = this.textInput;
      } else {
        this.msg.snackBar = 'Please enter text...';
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>(not included)</style>
```

**Here is my Pinia store:**

```
export const useSiteStore = defineStore('site', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      msg: {
        snackBar: '',
        login: '',
      },
    };
  },
```

**When I check the console, this is what it points to:**

```
(function anonymous(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, __vsfcl_import__) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: true
    });
    exports.render = render;
    var _vue = require("vue");
    const _hoisted_1 = {
        class: "snackbar"
    };
    function render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
        return (0,
        _vue.openBlock)(),
        (0,
        _vue.createElementBlock)("div", _hoisted_1, (0,
        _vue.toDisplayString)(_ctx.msg.snackBar), 1);
    }
}
)
```

I appreciate any insight and help with this in advance. thank you.

I simply tried to isolate the problem and followed the console to the origin of the problem, but I am not sure how to fix the warning or perhaps best-practice in this regard.

Here is a link to the live app: [Live App](https://test.k1pro.net/)

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Currently it looks like regular pinia code that can't cause such warning, msg.snackBar isn't changed anywhere

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The VueDev tools should work when you open the link. The warning should appear in the console, it does at least for me when I open with Chrome. Here is a link to the live app: [Sample](https://test.k1pro.net)

Comment: Please, provide all relevant info in the question body itself in addition to demo. Source code isn't directly available at that link. As far as I can see, there are no problems with app logic that could cause this warning. Could be pinia bug https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/2585 , but I suspect it's specific to the setup, i.e. vue3-sfc-loader. It's unofficial and it can do some unconventional things due to the way it works. Can you reproduce it without the loader in a conventional setup like stackblitz (vue cli or vite)?

Comment: Hi, thank you once again for your replies. I have updated to Vue 3.4.21 and this specific warning no longer appears. Now that I think of it, this warning has appeared in a previous version as well, but in other versions it did not. It is possible that the root cause of the error is the  vue3-sfc-loader, but this is something that I am not worried about. I am more worried about the core VueJS and Pinia concepts themselves. Essentially if I am using computed properties along with Pinia properly, then the rest of the setup here is irrelevant. I will do further tests though and update just in case

Comment: You're welcome. The code itself looks ok so far, I wouldn't worry, unless there are real issues besides this warning